# Redux with combined data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working with web3 that includes connections to data fetching from smart contracts and other libraries. In the end I created 2 slices

- 1 smart contract slices that fetches data from smart contracts like the circulating Supply
- 1 slice for prices data

Then in many pages accross the app I use a metric called the "MarketCap" which is a computation between the price data
:

```
marketCap = circulatingSupply * price
```

In a Root component I do this :

```
...
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(initializeProviderContracts({ networkID: chainID, provider }));
        dispatch(getBlockchainData(provider));
        dispatch(getMarketPrices());
    }, [connected]);
...
```

What I do is this for each component :

Comp

```
const component = () => {

// get the states 
const price = useSelector(state => state.market.price);
const circulatingSupply = useSelector(state => state.contracts.token.circulatingSupply);

const marketCap = price * circulatingSupply; // Done several times 

}
```

I couldn't find any tips about this in Redux, what is the best approach for it ? Do I need to create another slice like `metrics` and add an extra dispatcher ?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(initializeProviderContracts({ networkID: chainID, provider }));
        dispatch(getBlockchainData(provider));
        dispatch(getMarketPrices());
        dispatch(computeMetrics()); // could be used to compute marketCap here
    }, [connected]);
```

Also is there a name for these type of redux operations ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For derived values, use a selector.

```
// somewhere

export const selectMarketCap = state => state.market.price * state.contracts.token.circulatingSupply;

// in your component

const marketCap = useSelector(selectMarketCap);
```